# 3 monitors with docking station not working

Tags: display

I have 2 ASUS 24” monitors and 1 Phillips 24” hdtv along with a usb c 3.0 docking station and a windows 10 laptop. The docking station has 1 vga and 2 display ports. I have the  2 ASUS monitors hooked up via vga and DP and they work fine. Immediately when I plug the HDTV in to the DP, it shows up BUT the ASUS monitor I have hooked up using DP immediately goes blurry. I’ve messed with every setting in the intel graphics settings and cannot get a crisp clear screen. The HDTV is also not crisp and clear regardless of the resolution I use.

The minute I unplug the second DP cable both ASUS monitors go back to being clear and crisp.

I’ve tested the cable and it works fine when I only use the two monitors. Same thing with the port on the docking station.

The HDTV works fine when plugged in to my other laptop - clear and crisp.

Laptop is a Lenovo thinkpad T470, docking station is thinkpad usb C type 40A9 and resolution I’m using is 1920x1080 60p

Comment: You've probably exceeded USB type-C bandwidth. Please provide laptop model, docking station model and display resolutions.

Comment: Laptop is a Lenovo thinkpad T470, docking station is think of usb C type 40A9 and resolution I’m using is 1920x1080 60p

Answer (score 1):

According to the *ThinkPad USB-C Dock User Guide*:

> **Maximum resolutions and refresh rates**
>
> To achieve better display experience, it is recommended that you
>   connect one or two external monitors to the dock at a time.
>
> - DP output only: 3840 x 2160 pixels (30 Hz)
> - VGA output only: 1920 x 1200 pixels (60 Hz)
> - DP and VGA simultaneous output: 1920 x 1080 pixels (60 Hz)
> - DP and DP simultaneous output: 1920 x 1080 pixels (60 Hz)

Comment: Ugh. Thanks though for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

After being told by everyone this is not possible, I was able to accomplish 1920x1080 on all 3 screens by connecting 2 via the docking station and one via the video output (hdmi) on the laptop itself.  Change power settings to do nothing when closing laptop lid, close the lid.. detect the displays and voila.

Give this a try.